# DataGridView -- Highlight Row That Has Late Items

Tags: c#, mysql, if-statement, datagridview

I am trying to highlight my datagridview rows that have items pass their return date.

I have a column name "Reservation_Return_Date" in my datagridview.  The format of the text is 06/10/2015.

If the current date is greater than "Reservation_Return_Date", then the row is highlighted.

Below is a code that I found from another post.  What am I doing wrong?

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in CheckOut_dataGridView.Rows)
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var expirationDate = DateTime.Parse(row.Cells["Reservation_Return_Date"].Value.ToString());


        if (now > expirationDate)
        {
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        }


    }
```

Comment: have you checked expirationDate value?

Answer (score 0):

Rather use the CellFormatting event to change the backColor.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (DateTime.Compare((DateTime)dataGridView1.Rows[e.Index].Cells["Reservation_Return_Date"],DateTime.Now)>0)
        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
}
```

*May be it's "<0" instead of ">0" in date comparison*